# glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES returns wrong sizes

Tags: ios, ios5, opengl-es

I am currently working on a iOS app which needs to draw on the renderbuffer of its views. These views can be resized with a gesture, and as a result, I am resizing the renderbuffer.

However, when a user resizes the view to fast, `glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);` returns wrong values.

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

if(NO == [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer]) {
    NSLog(@"renderBufferStorage unsucessful!");
}
NSLog(@"_ %d %d", (int)self.layer.bounds.size.width, (int)self.layer.bounds.size.height);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) 
    NSLog(@"+ %d %d", backingWidth, backingHeight);
```

Slow resizing yields the following output (which would be more or less okay):

```
_ 452 321
+ 450 319
_ 453 322
+ 452 321
_ 453 322
+ 452 321
_ 453 323
+ 453 323
```

while fast resizing (here growing, than shrinking) gives me the following output (which not okay, the differences are to big)

```
 _ 491 350
 + 456 325
 _ 555 394
 + 491 348
 _ 548 390
 + 554 394
 _ 540 384
 + 548 390
 _ 459 326
 + 539 383
 _ 389 277
 + 459 326
 _ 313 222
 + 389 275
```

I have already tried to delay the resizing artificially or call the resize-function again, if I am not happy with the results (immediately and delayed) - both without success.

A solution which would be quite/too difficult to incorporate in the existing code would be rendering in a texture and then drawing the texture over the view. Is there anything I am missing about renderbuffers / EAGLDrawable or is the API not suitable for realtime resizing?

I have already checked for glErrors without any results.

Comment: Where is the code that you posted running? Is it on the main thread? Is it in a CADisplayLink callback?

Comment: It is called in the main thread (com.apple.main-thread) via layoutSubviews. The stack trace looks like:
`0 - [MyClass resize]
1 - [MyClass layoutSubviews]
2 - [UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why this is happening, but here are some thoughts:

Perhaps the layer's backing store has not been updated at `layoutSubviews` time. You could try moving this to a `CADisplayLink` callback and see if you get any better results.

Another alternative would be to use `GLKView` if you're targeting iOS 5+, or maybe allow the `CALayer` to scale its contents during live-resize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried moving the resizing code to a display link but unfortunately same problems occurred. It seems that the backing buffer really isn't resized properly, since repeated (like in the display link) queries for the size return the same result.

Could you please clarify what you mean by "allow the CALayer to scale its contents during live-resize"?

Comment: I mean that you could avoid resizing your render buffer until after the live-resize is complete, and using an appropriate content mode on the CALayer to keep things looking OK. I really don't see why this should be required, though.